# Facebook: "An access token is required to request this resource" in canvas only

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-canvas

The Facebook Javascript API fails in the canvas but works fine when I access the app directly. I get the "An access token is required to request this resource" error whenever I try to make a facebook query. I tried `getLoginStatus` but the callback never gets called in the canvas. However it does get called in the direct webpage. See this code:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
        appId      : '{{ app_id }}', // App ID
        status     : true, // check login status
        cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
        xfbml      : true, // parse XFBML
        frictionlessRequests : true
    });

    console.log("INIT");

    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        alert("GOT STATUS");
        alert(response);
    },true);
};

(function(d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

"INIT" is always output, but the alerts are only called when I access the page directly.

Edit: Here is the problematic app: https://apps.facebook.com/quirkyversaries/

The problem occurs when you try to create a new occasion and search for friends. The search fails due to the issue explained above. It also fails when you try to create a page occasion as the pages will not load.

Comment: App id you put into the JS code the same as the app your are actually loading in canvas? Can you give us the link to your app on FB?

Comment: Yes, the app ID is correct. I'll disable sandbox mode and post a link in the question...

Comment: Well, the search is working fine when I tried.

Comment: I can't login to your application: `Refused to display 'https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=522652504430995&redirect_ur…m/&scope=user_likes,friends_birthday,manage_pages,friends_likes,user_likes' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'DENY'. ` - you probably try to display app login url inside canvas iframe - you should open app login url in top frame: `top.location.href="loginurl"`

Comment: Mikolaj. If I redirect the top frame, how do I get facebook to redirect me back to the app in the canvas?

Comment: I'm trying to implement it through a double redirect.

Comment: I managed to get the login to work fine for me. The only downside is that at least 4 redirects are used which is silly but nevermind. The problem still remains.

Comment: Or maybe not. The problem has not resolved itself with me... Hmm, I'm not sure how. Perhaps I should make an answer showing how I went about logging in users?

Comment: You can just set the redirect URL - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/oauth/

Comment: i am not able to visit the link you have provided in the question. it says 404

Comment: The link should work again.

Comment: But the link works. It's only the local version that seems to be a problem.

Comment: its a bit obvious question, but does your local system have public IP? Infact, the domain name corresponding to your app should be the same as that of your local system. Fb is quite touchy about that

Comment: OK, so basically Facebook doesn't work with local IPs? It was never explained anywhere that this would be a problem.

Comment: yes. it requires the same domain name (or a public IP) for working

Answer (score 1):

1)   the app will either invoke the `callback function`, or it will redirect to the   `redirect_url`
  so, in case you have specified the `redirect_url`, kindly remove

2) according to the [docs](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/)

- you must subsscribe to the event `auth.statuschange`

  ```
   FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', function(response) {
   // do something with response
   });
  ```
- it is a bad practice to include a `true` at the end of the `getLoginStatus` function as you are invoking it on every page load. this true forces a roundtrip call. Since you have `status:true` in fb.init, you may not need that

Comment: Sorry, but I do not understand what you mean by the first part and I tried `FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange'...` but the callback is not called.

Comment: have you mentioned any redirect_url for your fb login? can you type the URL that you are hitting directly? the link in your question gives 404

Comment: The problem is occurring on the local version and the redirect is http://0.0.0.0:5000/login.

Comment: and what have you mentioned in your app's defination? See, the IP(or domain name) that you mention as your `site_url` should resolve to the domain name(IP) performing that `init`.   Also, if you have mentioned 'redirect_url' for login callback function WILL NOT BE CALLED